# MariaDB fails to start due to missing file /var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control

Tags: mariadb

MariaDB 10.3 refuses to start due to missing aria_log_control file.

Error:

```
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "restart" failed.
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.16 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf, tokudb.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-09-18 19:19:47 UTC; 8ms ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
  Process: 15645 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c rm /var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 15634 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 8115 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 18 19:19:47 <redacted> systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3.16 database server...
Sep 18 19:19:47 <redacted> mysqld[15645]: rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control': No such file or directory
Sep 18 19:19:47 <redacted> systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 18 19:19:47 <redacted> systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 18 19:19:47 <redacted> systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.16 database server.
```

It's basically saying it cannot remove `/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control` but that file does not exist...

Began happening after recovering from some f/s corruption

Answer (score 0):

Updating to MariaDB 10.3.18 fixed the problem